# Correct and technical terminology for the process of converting a traditional procedure to a more modern and systematic one

Tags: terminology, technology

The title is pretty self-explanitory,
what would be the correct and technical term to use for the process of "converting an old and traditional procedure of doing something (usually related to bureaucratic and company related tasks)" to a new and modern (powered by technology) one.

Comment: What would be wrong with the simple "*modernise*"?

Comment: Looking afresh to simplify an established, perhaps clumsy, process sounds like *streamlining* it.

Comment: Possibly "update"

Answer (score 1):

Probably [digitalize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/digitalize) (digitize) may fit in your context:

> to convert (something, such as data or an image) to digital form.